# How to merge two tensor?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to merge two tensors `a` and `b` into `c`. What I've tried is:

[image]

But my expectation is `c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. How can I get it?

Comment: `tf.concat([a, b], axis=0)`? Also please do not include screenshots of code and outputs, but rather paste them as text in the question.

Comment: You are right, it works! Thank you. Maybe you can paste it as the answer and I'd like to put it as the right one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) concatenate the given tensors along a new dimension. If you want to concatenate across an existing dimension, use [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat):

```
c = tf.concat([a, b], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with torch tensors, as [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-join-tensors-in-pytorch#:%7E:text=torch.cat()%20is%20used,0%20dimension%2C%20%2D1%20dimension.) suggests, you can do as following:

```
import torch

a = torch.Tensor([1,2,3])
b = torch.Tensor([4,5,6])
torch.cat((a,b))
```

output:

> tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])

and for stacking:

```
torch.stack((a,b))
```

output:

> tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
> [4., 5., 6.]])